# How can I insert all the files names in a folder into Access table?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm a begginer in Access and VBA coding and I would love to list all files names I have in a folder into my access table (ID (automatic), File Name) ?

Comment: Look at `DIR` look at `FileSystemObject` I think looping files in VBA should give you a google answer, also searching on here should. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380312/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-using-vba and also `SQL Insert`

Comment: I did, I used DIR but it shows nothing to me, because all I can find is excel examples with "Cells" function, I wanna insert the names in my table (called table1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim F as Variant, FSO As Object
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Docmd.SetWarnings False
For each F in FSO.getFolder("Path to your folder").Files
    Docmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO table1 ([FieldName]) VALUES ('" & F & "');"
Next
Docmd.SetWarnings True
```

Comment: Thank you ! it is working !! but how can I show only the file name ?

Comment: with or without the extension (e.g. .exe)?

Comment: F.Name gives me the name with extension, but just for knowing, how to show only the extension ?

Comment: You can use the FSO functions: FSO.getBaseName(F) is without the extension. FSO.getExtensionName(F) is just the extension. Here's the reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tkce7xa(v=vs.84).aspx

Answer (score 0):

So, all files into ONE table?

http://www.accessmvp.com/KDSnell/EXCEL_Import.htm#ImpFolderFiles

Or, all files into SEPARATE tables?

http://www.accessmvp.com/KDSnell/EXCEL_Import.htm#ImpAllWkshtsFilesSepTbls