# Auto select all item in file dialog in vba access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have vba access code that open file dialog and select item in special folder , I want auto select all item in this folder

```
Dim dialog As FileDialog
Dim filePath As String
Dim fileName As String

Set dialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With dialog
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .InitialFileName = "D:\MyTest\"
    .Show
    If .SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
        filePath = .SelectedItems.Item(1)

        Me.imgp = filePath
    End If
End With
```

Comment: If you want all the files, why do you need to display the file dialog at all? The file dialog is to allow the user to select one or more files; if you're doing it yourself, you don't need to display it for the user.

Comment: Sounds like you want the user to pick a folder, in which case `Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)` might be a better approach

Comment: I want to get the path of all item in a folder to table

Comment: I try this code but I can't select all of them

Comment: Code has to loop through files in folder to 'select' - grab file names. What do you want to do with files?

Comment: I want to get all files path in folder and insert it to table

Comment: For i =1 to fd.SelectedItems.Count     St=“D:\MyTest\”.     Imgp= fd.SelectedItems.Item(i)

Comment: I try this code but I can’t select all item

Comment: You want to enter file path as a string into field? Do you want one record for each filename? Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-59.html

Comment: Also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38480430/how-can-i-insert-all-the-files-names-in-a-folder-into-access-table

Comment: Yes , I want one record for each file name

Comment: Follow referenced examples, attempt code and if still have issue, edit question or start a new one.